# The IP address of my Azure Windows VM changed without waning

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

A few days ago, the IP address of our VB Windows Server changed from 40.x.x.x to 13.x.x.x on the Azure platform. We have many loggers in the field that connect to this IP address and now, none of them can connect.

Can the IP change without any warning from Azure?

Also, there is no support to be found. No number, no online support... I mean, This is not a problem I should be paying support for... besides.. support is more expensive than the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP address will change if, for instance, you restart your virtual machine. However, you can set this to be static by doing so:

1. go to **Public IP addresses**
2. Click **Configuration**
3. Set assignment to **Static**
4. Click **Save**

This will retain the IP address that you have right now but at an additional cost.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the IP change without any warning from Azure?

For now, there is no warning when public IP address change. I think you should know [IP address types and allocation methods in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm).

There are two methods in which an IP address is allocated to a public IP resource - `dynamic` or `static`. The default allocation method is `dynamic`, where an IP address is not allocated at the time of its creation. Instead, the public IP address is allocated when you start (or create) the associated resource (like a VM or load balancer). **The IP address is released when you stop (or delete) the resource. This causes the IP address to change when you stop and start a resource**.

If you want to public IP address not change, you could change `dynamic` to `static`.

[image]